# google speech API does only partial transcript

Tags: google-speech-api, pause, transcription

I am trying to transcribe some FLAC files using google-speech-cloud (speech API). I am using the long_running_recognize (asynch) and the result is only a partial transcription - basically the first sentence. It seems that when the pause occurs, it stops processing. The audio returned was only for the first 15-20 seconds or so of the 2 minute file.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Mal